# PHP return is adding spaces, even with trim()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a function that should report a boolean, but it's adding spaces to the front of the string. Even with trim(), the spaces remain... What is causing this?

**PHP**

```
function a($v){
  $r = is_file($v) ? 1 : 0;
  return(trim($r));
}
```

**JS**

```
$.ajax(url+query,{ success:function(data){ return(data); } });
```

**Output**

```
    1
```

***Update***

I'm invoking using `$_GET`, calling the function depending on the parameter past in the query. This is the first time I've had this issue, everything else works fine. *I don't think this has any thing to do with spaces in the file - it doesn't occur anywhere else, and I'm only returning what's in the function..*

Comment: are you sure there's actual spaces there? it's not css padding/margin stuff? is_file returns a boolean value, not a string, so your trim() call is totally useless anyways: your ternary is assigning ints, not strings. so there's NOTHING to trim in the first place

Comment: How are you invoking the function exactly? You might have white space in your output before printing the result.

Comment: Besides being able to simplify to `function a($v){return (int) is_file($v); }` check to see if there's anything elsewhere in your code that adds spaces; because `return` certainly doesn't.... e.g. where are you calling your `a()` function? and how are you returning the response from that to your browser?

Comment: Please post a full, complete, working example that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Just being a bit picky about your wording here, but you're not returning a boolean (or an integer, for that matter) from your function.  You're returning a string.

Comment: @Crontab It can be returned to an int using `parseInt()` in JS. That isn't the issue.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Other than the invoke and output methods, all relevant code is there...

Comment: No it is not, you have to call the function somehow and print the result.

Comment: Then show the output methods, because there's noting in the code that you've posted that will demonstrate the symptons you're showing: how are you calling the function and how are you returning the result?

Comment: I didn't really think that relevant to the issue.. it's being called and output. AJAX via `$_GET` parameters and output, let's say `alert()`. End result - check if file exists before overwrite.

Comment: It's clearly relevant that something else in your PHP code is outputting those whitespace characters if `ob_clean()` is the solution.... you really should fix the problem, not work round it

Comment: @kcdwayne I fully understand that, like I said I was just being picky about your wording.  It's important to use the right vocabulary on a site like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have spaces in the PHP files you include. You must encode your file in UTF8 without Bom. And remove "?>" at the end of your files.

Verify all your files, or you can use :

```
function a($v){
  $r = is_file($v) ? 1 : 0;
  ob_clean();
  return $r;
}
```

But this is the easy way, don't use ob_clean() and verify your files ! :)

Comment: Please note that this `ob_clean()` trick is a workaround just to verify what your problem is, you still have a problem with extra white space somewhere and it may come back to haunt you again.

Comment: I agree, as I have said, you shouldn't use ob_clean(), it just reveal that you have a problem !

Comment: I do have some spaces where PHP is mixed with HTML (outside of PHP tags). This is the 1st time it's occurred, and due to the simplicity of this function I'm not too worried unless more issues occur. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what causing it but maybe try below code :

```
return (int) $r
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  //<----   check for white space here
  <?php
  function a($v){
    $r = is_file($v) ? 1 : 0;
    return(trim($r));
  } 
  ?>
  //<----   or here here
```

They're probably the most common cause of unexpected php white space output